# Stop a Task with a CancelationToken

Tags: c#, task, cancellation-token

I have a class that represents a custom `Task`.
This class has an `Execution` method that returns the `IEnumerable<string>` of all the inside `yield return` statement, and a `Start` method that calls the enumerable, thus executing the lazy code.

My problem is that I have also a `Stop` method that basically cancels the token associated with the `Start` method by using:

```
TokenSource.CancelAfter(delay);
TokenSource.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
```

This code actually stops the running task, but how can I handle the exception? This is not done inside the actual `Task`.

Any ideas on how to handle the stop?

---

An example I've been using to test this part:

```
public class FunctionTask : Awaitable
{
    public FunctionTask(string code, Scheduler scheduler = null) 
    : base(code, scheduler)
    { }

    public override IEnumerable<string> Execution()
    {
         for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
         {
             yield return WaitFor(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10d))
                 .WithDescription($"Step {i + 1}, waiting 1 second");
         }

        yield return "Done";
    }
}
```

And these are the (inherited) start and stop methods:

```cs
public Task Start()
{
    stopRequested = false;
    Status.Value = TaskStatus.WaitingToRun;

    Task task = new Task(() =>
        {
            Status.Value = TaskStatus.Running;

            try
            {
                // Iterate through the Execution task state
                IEnumerable<string> executionState = Execution();
                foreach (string state in executionState)
                    WaitState.Value = state;

                // And then through the termination task state
                IEnumerable terminationState = Termination();
                foreach (string state in terminationState)
                    WaitState.Value = state;

                Status.Value = TaskStatus.RanToCompletion;
            }
            catch (Exception ex) // This may be caused by a stop request or an actual exception
            {
                Status.Value = TaskStatus.Faulted;

                if (stopRequested)
                    Logger.Error(ex);
                else
                    Logger.Warn($"Task with code {Code} faulted because a stop has been requested");
            }
        },
        TokenSource.Token
    );

    task.Start(Scheduler);
    return task;
}
```

```cs
public virtual void Stop()
{
    if (Status.Value == TaskStatus.Running || Status.Value == TaskStatus.WaitingToRun)
    {
        stopRequested = true;

        TokenSource.Cancel();
        TokenSource.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested(); // Let the task fail and then stop

        Status.Value = TaskStatus.Canceled;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `Execution()` method needs access to the `CancellationToken` (either as method parameter or as private field of the instance) and must regulary check its state. If the state is set, the method has to return or to throw, depending on your needs. But there is nothing you can do _from outside the method_.

Comment: Or alternative, it can use the `Register` method to add a callback that does something active that can stop cancellation, for example disposing a socket or marking a `Channel<T>` as completed (or whatever you need to actually stop things). As a side note: for async, maybe `IAsyncEnumerable` is worth looking at (over `IEnunerable`)

Comment: Can you please add a full [mre]?

Comment: Why are you calling `TokenSource.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();` immediately after the `TokenSource.Cancel();`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the property [IsCancellationRequested](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtoken.iscancellationrequested?view=net-8.0) if you don't want to throw the OperationCanceledException.

In the Stop method just call `TokenSource.Cancel()` and remove the `TokenSource.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()`, it doesn't make sense there.

Then use the `IsCancellationRequested` property to stop the enumeration, something like:

```
foreach (string state in executionState)
{
    if(token.IsCancelltionRequested)
        break;

    WaitState.Value = state;
}
```